# Django: HTML tags displayed as text

Tags: python, django

In my Django application, the `<acronym>...</acronym>` tag is displayed as `&lt;acronym title=&#39;Особо охраняемая прирордная территория&#39;&gt;ООПТ&lt;/acronym&gt;`.

The template looks like this (the acronym tag appears in `cur_goal.description`).

```
{% extends "base.tpl.html" %}

{% block title %}{{ genplan.name }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>{{ category_name }}</h2>
    {% for cur_goal in goals %}
        <li>{{ cur_goal.description }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}

{% block right_sidebar %}
{% endblock %}
```

How can I change the code so that the acronym tag is displayed correctly (the braces are not replaced by `&lt;` and `&gt;`) ?

Comment: Acronym is deprecated and won't work correctly in HTML5.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/acronym

Comment: @ben336 Is there any replacement for it?

Comment: use <abbr> instead.  More info in the link I posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As DM says, autoscape tag, or... the safe filter

```
    <li>{{ cur_goal.description|safe }}</li>
```

Or `mark_safe` from the python side.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe